# Yeoman Generator error this.log = this.env.adapter.log;

Tags: javascript, wordpress, node.js, generator, yeoman

I'm having a hell of time debugging this error - looking for another set of eyes on it.

I've forked Romain Berger's Yeoman Wordpress generator to modify for my workflow, github repo here: 
https://github.com/mykepreuss/yeoman-wordpress

npm link to my generator here:
https://npmjs.org/package/generator-assembly-wp

After I install it and run:  `yo assembly-wp` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-assembly-wp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:79
  this.log = this.env.adapter.log;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
    at Generator.Base (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-assembly-wp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:79:30)
    at new Generator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-assembly-wp/app/index.js:17:26)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/env/index.js:325:10)
    at Environment.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/env/index.js:361:24)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:95:7)
    at pre (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:108:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:134:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use Generator system 0.15 (which is not in stable release) with `yo` 1.0.6.

Either run your Generator with 0.14 and `yo` 1.0.6. Or run your Generator with 0.15.0-pre.1 and `yo` 1.0.7-pre.1

(BTW, bug noted and there'll be a fix before the official full release)

Comment: Where do I look for the Generator system version @simon-boudrias - thanks for the help, would like to know your troubleshooting method.

Comment: Like every node.js modules, in the `package.json` file. For `yo`, as it is a global package, just run `npm ls -g --depth=0` and check the version it gives you. To install an ulterior version, just run `npm install <package>@<version>`.

Comment: Ok, I see @simon-boudrias - thanks man, I had no idea about that. Much appreciated!